# Copy a class so that the old class is not modified when I modify the new one in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, functional-programming

I have some a `ConnectFour` class and I have a method:

```
def apply_move!(column_number, symbol, row_number = 0)
  # Some gravity logic
  @board[row_number][column_number] = symbol
end
```

That modifies the class in place.

I tried writing a wrapper around it that returns a board and does not change the original, so that Function Programming techniques could be used.

My attempt is:

```
def apply_move(column_number, symbol)
  dummy = ConnectFour.new(@board)
  dummy.apply_move!(column_number, symbol)
  dummy
end
```

But the trouble is that modifying `dummy` also modifies the original class itself! How could I modify `dummy` and `dummy` only?

**More code and context**

You probably are interested in:

```
class CpuWinIfPossible < Player
  def decide_move(board)
    (0...6).find do |move|
      board.apply_move(move, self.symbol).is_won?(self.symbol)
    end || (0...6).to_a.sample
  end
end
```

Here I loop and execute `apply_move` to my board, as you can see from my definition above, `apply_move` should not change the board, but the board shows 7 (+ 1) moves after this code is run: it looks like this:

```
Player X: Where would you like to play (Number from 1 to 7) ? 
2




 O   O 
OXOOOO 
The winner is O
```

**The constructor**

```
class ConnectFour
  attr_accessor :board


  def initialize(board)
    @board = board
  end
```

Comment: I don't understand how any of the methods you showed could conceivably mutate the class. There must be something else going on you're not showing us. Also, what do you mean by "old class" and "new class"? I can only see one class here, `ConnectFour`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag added a significant method, probably my terminology was not precise as when I said class, I really meant a variable containing a particular instance of the class

Comment: Please can share the constructor method of `ConnectFour`? I'm pretty sure there is the issue, Don't send `@board` instead send `@board.clone` or `@board.dup`

Comment: @Aguardientico added, thanks for your effort even if my question is incomplete :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is related to the current status of @board, if you change your `ConnectFour#initialize` to looks like following I think it should be work

```
def initialize(board)
  @board = board.dup
end
```

If you are using rails you can use `deep_dup`

```
def initialize(board)
  @board = board.deep_dup
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, so the problem was that `@board` was really shared by all COnnectFour instances?

Comment: Wait a second I think I still got the problem, I thank you very much anyway

Comment: This will only duplicate the `@board` array, not the arrays contained within the `@board` array. The *real* problem is that Ruby is an object-oriented language, not an array-of-arrays-of-integers-oriented language, so you should really use a `Board` object for your board, not an array-of-arrays-of-integers.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I understand that the problem is more deep than it seemed, the lack of support that Ruby shows comes from my non-compliance to OO

Comment: it looks like rails has a `deep_dup` method http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/Array/deep_dup  updating the answer

Answer (score 1):

A hack to solve my problem is:

```
def initialize(board)
  @board = board.map(&:dup)
end
```

But as @JörgWMittag noted I should really make my code more OO to fit with Ruby style and this workaround will not be needed anymore.

Comment: @admdrew I am talking to myself in second person to make the post more readable for future visitors

Comment: @admdrew first person now.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a deep copy of the class:

```
new_class = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(ConnectFour))
```

and go from there (`dummy = new_class.new(@board)`, etc.).